# Python 3: find previous/next element in for loop

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x

This question has been answered before for Python 2.x. I can not get it to work in Python 3.

I changed `izip` to `zip`, because I understood izip was removed from Python 3.

```
from itertools import tee, islice, chain

def previous_and_next(some_iterable):
    prevs, items, nexts = tee(some_iterable, 3)
    prevs = chain([None], prevs)
    nexts = chain(islice(nexts, 1, None), [None])
    print(zip(prevs, items, nexts))

a = list(range(1,10))

previous_and_next(a)
```

Running this gives me `<zip object at 0x7f338e4ea638>`

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<zip object at 0x7f338e4ea638>` is an iterator. To obtain the items in the iterator one must pass it to `tuple()` or `list()`.
Specifically, replace `print(zip(prevs, items, nexts))` with `print(tuple(zip(prevs, items, nexts)))` or `print(list(zip(prevs, items, nexts)))`